# Finding last assignments of an event per customer

Tags: google-sheets

I have [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13dw65Ce6cb4Ryz_AP0LFyTur5VNHhRTXWIv9TBM1T2c/edit?usp=sharing) sheet: A1 - Event Date, B1 - Type of Event, C1 - Customer Name, D1 - Rep.

The sheet shows the whole history of when a specific rep has been assigned to take care of a specific customer and when he is no longer responsible for a certain client.

What I need to accomplish is to make a query or filter (or something else) that will show me each rep that was last assigned to a Customer name.

```
Event Date Type of Event   Customer Name   Rep
01/01/2016  Assign  AAA Dani
01/01/2016  Assign  BBB David
10/02/2016  Assign  CCC Carol
10/02/2016  Assign  DDD Carol
10/02/2016  Exclude AAA Dani
10/02/2016  Assign  AAA Carol
```

The result would look like:

```
Expected output of the function
Customer Name   Rep
AAA             Carol
CCC             Carol
DDD             Carol
BBB             David
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you start with a column of the unique customer names by putting :

```
=UNIQUE(C:C)
```

Then in a column to the right of it you put:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(D:D,C:C=H2),COUNTA(FILTER(D:D,C:C=H2)))
```

then copy down.

Basically what I'm doing in filtering to only show the names for each customer, then by wrapping it in a counta function , you will get the max number of times it occurs - finally and index function to return the last row available within the filter

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to get everything in one formula, try

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(VLOOKUP(unique(C2:C), query(A2:D, "select C, D, max(A) where B='Assign' group by C, D", 0), {1,2}, 0)))
```

This should auto-update the output when new rows are added.